# How to prevent session hijacking with a user's session in CGI Perl?

Tags: perl, session, cgi

I have a web app used by a small number of people (internal only) and am using a randomised sessionID that is stored under the user record and placed in various links.

I have had a problem where users are sending links to each other which is allowing them to hijack the sender's session.

What are some ways of preventing this from happening while still letting users send links to one another?

Edit:
The session ID in the link (which also contains $username) is just compared to what is stored in the User table. &incorrectLogin just prints an error followed by die;

```
if ($sid) {

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_User WHERE UserID = '$username'");
    $sth->execute();

    $ref         = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
    $session_chk = $ref->{'usr_sessionID'};

    unless ($sid eq $session_chk) {

        &incorrectLogin;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if someone uses a link that is created by someone else, the page will load as them. I am not using cookies, and I recall being told in the past that CGI perl cookie handling is quite poor.

Comment: We're going to need to know a little more. What do you use for authentication? Do you set cookies on the user's machine? Why are you using the querystring for sessionId? Can we see some code?

Comment: Ah my apologies. I have added some additional information to the original post.

Answer (score 4):

If the query string contains all of the information you're using for session authentication, then you're hosed by design. You are going to need to find some way of putting either the username, or the session ID, or more preferably both, into a cookie; otherwise, you're just going to be SOL, because you have no way to prevent links sent by users from containing everything that your code uses to tell which user it's talking to.

Were I you, I'd start by finding out whether CGI.pm does as poor a job with cookies as I'd been told, and if so, I'd proceed to rolling my own Cookie: headers. The only other alternative I can see is to convert all the links in your application to POST requests, which is both even more broken and too horrible to contemplate.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the solution lies in taking at least some of the authentication out of the URL. I have no experience with using cookies  yet so I'm first just trying to find the best place to start learning.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the query string (or the session id) should not contain the user id. When you receive the session id, you look at the session information stored on the server side to retrieve the user id associated with that session id.

Second, you should expire sessions after a certain amount of inactivity.

Third, you can store two extra items in the server side session to help you combat this while still not using cookies. The solution is not perfect, i.e. there is still an opportunity to hijack a session, but makes it more difficult.

On the server side, store the IP address from which the user logged on. If you receive a subsequent request for the same session from a different IP, ask for credentials again. Do not include the IP address in the query string.

In addition, with every response, generate a `next_request_id`. Store this in the server side session, and send it back to the client as well. All the links on the page you return will have to include this `next_request_id` as well.

When you receive a request, check if the `next_request_id` you received is the same as the one you had stored for that session. If not, re-authenticate.

Now, this will interfere with the users' ability to use the site with multiple tabs or using reload/refresh, but it was an appropriate solution for me in a specific use case.

But, in the general case, you're better off using cookies.

Sessions can still be hijacked when using [cookies over plain HTTP](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted.html), but, at least, you're guarding against this particular failure.

Answer (score 3):

I used to handle session management very much like you are doing now, before switching to cookies.  Now, I use [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Session-4.48/lib/CGI/Session.pm), and am very happy with it.

**However**, if you would like a slightly quicker hack to solve your problem in the short term, one thing you can do is to store the IP address of each session along with the session id.  Then, if an incoming IP address/session id pair does not match what you have stored, you can redirect to your login page.

This approach does have some pitfalls and is not perfect, but it does close the big security hole you have at the moment.